# BAT удаление программы

Tags: java, windows, bat

Есть необходимость удалять старые версии своего ПО, при выходе обновления. Проще Всего мне кажется, это сделать через bat файл, чтобы не напрягать пользователя. В гугле есть варианты с использование wmic, однако данная утилита позволяет увидеть только те программы, которые были установлены при помощи Microsoft Installer. В реестре

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

тоже нет моего софта. Какие еще существую варианты?

Comment: Зачем вам uninstall при обновлении?

Comment: @vp_arth потому, что в случае обновления у меня просто скачивается и запускается инсталятор более новой версии. И при обновлении, у пользователя в программах накапливаются мои ПО разных версий. Старые версии недоступны, но в самой панели управления остаются упоминания о них.

Comment: Может должен запускаться не инсталлятор, а обновлятор?

Comment: *в случае обновления у меня просто скачивается и запускается инсталятор более новой версии.* Вот он и должен озаботиться удалением предыдущих версий, если они присутствуют, а юзер не против.

Comment: @Akina ну вот я и хочу встроить запуск бат файла, если была обнова.

Comment: >> И при обновлении, у пользователя в программах накапливаются мои ПО разных версий. Т.е. у Вас в реестре есть запись о программе, если она светится в панели управления?

Comment: @Drop У Вас что, инсталлятор - это тупое копирование файлов в каталог мимо штатной процедуры установки приложений?

Comment: Может стоит посмотреть в сторону распространения своего софта через msi-пакеты? http://wixtoolset.org/ или чё-нить другое.